# What is URL scheme for writing a facebook post

Tags: android, html, facebook

I want to open write post screen of Facebook in my Android device when I click on a particular Facebook share URL in my browser. How I can write the URL scheme for the same for Android?

P.S : (I want to open the screen in my installed Facebook App..not in the browser.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Refer following link you may solved your problem 
[Wiki akosma](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes,)

Comment: I have understood that its not possible to launch the dialog box through URL because there's no URL scheme available for it. But thanks for your time